# jQuery - find tag in a string by its innerHTML and add attribute to it

Tags: jquery, find

I have the following piece of code in my HTML file

```
   <select>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <!-- ......... -->
        <option>50000</option>
   </selcet>
```

using jQuery I get

```
      var subHTML=$("select").html();
```

Can I find an option tag by its innerHTML in subHTML string, insert attribute "selected" and then put the edited string back into the select tag

```
      $("select").html(editedString);
```

**Edit**

I tried

```
  var strel=$(subHtml).find('option:contains("123")').attr('selected','selected');
  $("select").html(strel);
```

but it adds only one option to the select tag.

Comment: which option you want to select?

Comment: any of them: for example 5 or 123 or 50000 etc. I want to get it by its innerHtml. It will be better if it can be done using jQuery.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. For some reasons I want to search an option tag in subHTML string. Because after making changes I insert the edited string into another place as well. (not into the same select tag). thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This should work. (Not tested).

```
var to_replace = $("select").find('option:contains("The text i want to find")');
to_replace.attr("selected", "selected");
to_replace.text("The new text");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('option').filter(function() {
   if(this.innerHTML === '123') {
      $(this).attr('its-me', 1);
      return true;
   }
   return false;
});
```

***Edit***, or just:

```
$('option').filter(function() {
   return this.innerHTML === '123';
}).attr('its-me', 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

[**jQuery Contains**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/) selector will help.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function()
    {
        var searchReplace = $("select").find('option:contains("editme")').attr("selected", "selected").text("foundme");
    });

</script>

<select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>editme</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>50000</option>
</selcet>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the working Sample :

[Select](http://jsfiddle.net/Rx3AP/620/)

If this is your HTML:

```
<select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
```

You can use :

```
$("select option").each(function(){
if ($(this).text() == "2")
   $(this).attr("selected","selected");
});
```